# Problems connecting to remote informix from NetBeans

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I am developing a web application with Java and NetBeans 8.0.2, which will connect to a remote informix engine, but within the same intranet.

I use frameworks are Hibernate 4.3.1 and Java Server Faces + PrimeFaces, which I liked a lot when I learned, but unfortunately, most of the examples are made with MySQL installed locally.

When I try to connect to remote informix engine, it rejects the connection me.

The connection string I'm using is:
jdbc:informix-sqli://192.168.40.97:1526/pruebas:INFORMIXSERVER=ol_develop

I've checked everything several times, and the user and password (not listed in the post), they are correctly entered.

So notorious, it is that if the connection string will remove the name of the base (pruebas), leaving this way:
jdbc:informix-sqli://192.168.40.97:1526:INFORMIXSERVER=ol_develop
NetBeans is connected to the engine and shows me the sysmaster, sysutils, and pruebas bases. But fails more than that, it can't show the structure of the base.

The JDBC I am using is the JDBC 3.70.JC6.

Anyone has happened something similar?

I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Regards!

Gustavo Echenique

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the username you are connecting with has no connect permissions to the pruebas database. Is the username something besides 'informix'?

Comment: Hi Pradeep, "informix" is the username of the database, is the user DBA.